# Are higher order interference peaks from a thin-film or multilayer of lower intensity, and if so why?

Tags: optics, visible-light, geometric-optics

I seem to remember that higher orders (m) of interference for a thin-film (or multilayer) are increasingly weaker in intensity. That is, the first order interference will always produce a peak of the greatest intensity. However, now that I try to find why this is, I can't find an answer, or even any source specifically supporting this. All I find is examples of Young's double slit experiment.

Yet, I do find that when I model a simple multilayer, that the first order interference peak is brighter than the second order.

So my question is, is my assumption correct, and if so why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that the higher order peaks have higher max intensity (peak reflectance), but they do have broader peaks. This follows simply from the math.

For the mth order interference, the wavelength that is optimally reinforced perfectly satisfies the condition $2nd=m \lambda $, for normal incidence. If m=1,2,3..., we have perfect interference. If it is slightly off (for example, 0.8 instead of 1), we have some interference, but less. The further from the optima, the less reinforcement until we hit the destructive point. Thus the interference peak is a smooth curve.

The difference in different orders of interference lay in how quickly/steeply this curve tapers off. Let's look at an example.

For a given optical thickness, let's say $2nd=400$, we can see what will happen for each order of interference when we deviate from the optimum by 10nm in each case. The closer we are to an integer, the better the interference. We can rewrite the equation as $2nd/\lambda$=m, to see what happens for different orders of interference.

**1st order:**

400/400=1 --> 1 is an integer, perfect interference

400/410=0.9756098 ---> start to taper off, but nearly perfect since almost 1

**2nd order**

400/200=2 --> 2 is an integer, perfect interference

400/210= 1.904762 ---> notice the relatively larger deviation from the integer 2 here

**5th order**

400/80=5 --> perfect interference

400/90= 4.444 ---> large deviation from the perfect condition (5)